# How to pass and retrieve values to/from popup window in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4, popupwindow

I want to send some text value to my custom popup window when it pops up from main application which is having some text input and also I want to know how to retrieve data(of text input) which entered by a user in popup window. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can access popUp data using setter as example shows. Or make a popUp component as a global  in your main application so you can refer component properties globally.

```
<!-- TitleWindow.mxml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<mx:TitleWindow xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" layout="absolute" width="600" title="" height="160">

<fx:Script>
       <![CDATA[            

           public function get UserTypedData():String
           {
                return tiSomeText.text;
           }
    ]]>
</fx:Script>

<fx:Declarations>
    <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
</fx:Declarations>
<mx:TextInput id="tiSomeText" x="76" y="101"/>
```

```
<!-- Application.mxml -->
<mx:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
            xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" layout="absolute" width="100%" >

<fx:Script>
    <![CDATA[                           
                public var popup:YourPopupWindow;

                private function createPopUp():void
                {
                    popup = YourPopupWindow(PopUpManager.createPopUp(this, YourPopupWindow, false));
                }

                private function getPopUpData():String
                {
                    var retVal:String = "";

                    if (popUp != null)
                    {
                        // get data from setter
                        retVal = popUp.UserTypedData();
                        // of from TextInput
                        retVal = popUp.tiSomeText.text;
                    }

                    return retVal;   
                }

    ]]>
</fx:Script>
</mx:Application>
```

Answer (score 4):

```
var popup:YourPopupWindow = PopupManager.createPopup(YourPopupWindow, true) as YourPopupWindow;
popup.someData = yourData;
```

Comment: Hi @J_A_X, here someData is a variable of main application or custom popup window's variable. Sorry, if its a silly question.

Comment: 'someData' is a public property in YourPopupWindow.